# DOM Manipulation using Angular or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs

What kind of conflicts happen when both Jquery and AngularJS are used together ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular is a framework. jQuery is a library for working with DOM. Only one of components of Angular framework called `directive` work with DOM, and they *do use* jQuery to do that. Actually, it uses its subset called `jqLite`. It's a personal choice whether you should use jQuery for manipulating DOM in custom directives or not, but since Angular itself uses it, I see no reason to not use it. And certainly, there will be no conflicts when Angular and jQuery are used together. In fact, Angular checks whether jQuery is available and uses it manipulate DOM intead of its built-in library jqLite.

If you're talking about whether in your custom directive's template you should use `ng-class` instead of adding classes to DOM elements manually, I would advice to use Angular's standard directive `ng-class`.

According to all best practices, the only place where you can manipulate DOM is from directives. And since you can't modify standard directive, custom directives is the only place where you can manipulate DOM. It's certainly bad practice to manipulate DOM inside controllers or services, regardless of whether you use jQuery or not.

Comment: Without any custom directive if one use it then it is good practice ?

Comment: According to all best practices, the only place where you can manipulate the DOM is from directives. And since you can't modify standard directives, custom directives is the only place where you can manipulate the DOM. It's certainly bad practice to manipulate DOM inside controllers or services, regardless of whether you use jQuery or not.

Comment: If one tries to modify a DOM element having standard directive with jquery from outside the Angular Scope then does it cause problem to digest cycle ? If yes how ?

Comment: @HoneyThakuria, please, ask new question, and it would be good if you provided some code example which clarifies this point _to modify a DOM element having standard directive with jquery from outside the Angular Scope_